# How can I update a CSS variable inside a selector not currently in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, css

Most practices have CSS variables in `:root` which are easily updated with:

`document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--variable", value);`

Is there a way of doing so for a selector not currently in the DOM without resorting to writing cssText? For example, setting `--variable` under `.SomeClass` which will later be added to the DOM.

Comment: I understand that you will add element dynamically with `.SomeClass` CSS class. Do you also want to dynamically create `--variable`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I follow.
Are you asking how to edit CSS variables that were not defined in the root? Or creating an element and settings a CSS variable as a property? One way to do both is by directly selecting an HtmlElement and then setting the property.

```
`const home = document.getElementById('home');`
`home.style.setProperty('--text-color', 'green');`
```